# How to get comment count from your wall posts without making a call to comments object for each post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

July 10 breaking changes introduces;

> **Removing 'count' from 'comments' Graph API connection**
>   *We are removing the undocumented 'count' field on the 'comments' connection in the Graph API. Please request
>   '{id}/comments?summary=true' explicitly if you would like the summary
>   field which contains the count (now called 'total_count')*

If I pull up me/feed, sure enough, count is no longer in the comments object. But how do I get the comment count without resorting to making a graph API call to the comments object on every post?

I'm not very good with field expansion, but is there a way to get the feed to include the summary?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not documented anywhere, even subfields or limits, I've found this asking in developers forum. this call pull PageID/posts with custom format. In my case here is how to pull Likes count, shares count and comments count in one call.

```
PageID/posts?fields=comments.limit(1).summary(true),likes.limit(1).summary(true),shares
```

I'm not really sure if you have to mark agreed the October api changes in order to get your custom format.

hope this work for you...

Comment: brilliant, thanks for that, I haven't tested it as yet but I'll take your word on it.

Comment: Superb! Have been looking all over for this. Seen various other thread where the accepted answer was a single FQL call or API call for each different object. This is brilliant and so much faster. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Some kind of obvious, but it doesn't work anymore :(