# total_count Not Returned as Promised by Object Likes Endpoint

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Graph API end point referenced below to grab the likes for an object on Facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/object/likes

The documentation indicates that I should expect to receive an array of User objects in addition to a field named `total_count`, which would represent the total number of likes the object has received.  I have not been able to get an API response that includes this value - either through my code or via the Graph Explorer.

Has this field already been deprecated? Is there an additional parameter anyone knows of that would trigger the attribute to be returned in the API response?

Is anyone aware of issues with using the solution [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17847926/1383003)?

```
PageID/posts?fields=comments.limit(1).summary(true),likes.limit(1).summary(true),shares
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of your query:

?summary=1

i.e. in graph explorer put: {object-id}/comments?summary=1

( object-id can be the post_id)

Then the total comment count is under this section:

"summary": {
    "order": "ranked", 
    "total_count": 24
  }